# Notification for amount of new messages with PHP

Tags: php, notifications

I have this form made with PHP. If the form is processed it writes everything in a .txt file and saves it on the server. It saves it like this $date_$name_$subject_1unread.txt.
With the snippet below a list is made so the files can be downloaded. The download.php file changes the filename from unread to read. So I have 2 lists with unread messages and read messages.

```
<p>Read</p>
<?php 
foreach (glob("*1unread.html") as $filename) {
    echo "{$filename}<a href='download.php?file=$filename'>Download</a><br>" . "\n" ;
}
?>  

<p>Unread</p>
<?php 
foreach (glob("*1read.html") as $filename) {
echo "{$filename}<a href='$filename'>Download</a><br>" . "\n" ;
}
?>
```

But my question is:
How do I make a notification, like a pop-up or in a HTML menubar with something like 'New messages ('amount of new messages') if there are new messages.

Comment: don't use a flat txt file a database would be much esier

Comment: But the file needs to be printable. How do I do that with a database?

Comment: you read from the db when you need to

Comment: Read from db? How will this make it printable? And by printable I mean printed on paper :P